# Windows Mobile - Is it possible to get list of calls?

Tags: windows-mobile

I want to save some data automaticly from phones to central db? Is that possible in Windows Mobile 6.0?

Comment: I found a really good example using the native API, see edit in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use native API and P/Invoke.
Here is a page with methods you can use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb416387.aspx
**Edit:** here is a useful example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows/wm_callhistory.aspx?msg=3213607

Another option is to use Smart Device Framework from OpenNETCF, the Community Edition is free.
The class OpenNETCF.Phone.CallLog is a wrapper around the native API.
Download: http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx
Documentation: http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/